# difficulty to keep color of ribbon same from source till end node in sankey diagram with flipplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

i am trying to create sankey diagram using below data set

```
my.data = data.frame(Married = c("Yes","Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"),
Pet = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"),
Happy = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"),
freq = 5:1)
```

I created the sankey plot using

```
library(flipPlots)
SankeyDiagram(my.data[, -4],
link.color = "Source", 
weights = my.data$freq)
```

the problem is that i want to keep the color of ribbon same from start to end i.e the ribbon color from source remain the same till the last node i.e happy and dont change after passing from pet

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Aisha, Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a link that allows for custom colors in ggsankey for Sankey plots; it uses `scale_fill_manual()`.  It's about 2/3rds of the way down: https://rpubs.com/techanswers88/sankey-with-own-data-in-ggplot

Comment: thank you so much David for your comment but  when i run the code all ribbons became greyish

Comment: Hi Aisha, you are almost there. The default for `scale_fill_manual` is to use a greyish ribbon color. You have to specify a bit more in `scale_fill_manual`. If you search that page on this: `="red"`, you will see examples on how to fill in the arguments to `scale_fill_manual(values = c(AishasColors))` (between the parentheses) that allow you to customize your colors.

Comment: thank you David for your response and help